# Twiiter Bootstrap (Button Dropdown) + Div Fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have two buttons in a div with position: fixed; but when you click, the list of options disappeared.

I wrote my code in the link below, you can help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/T9QHw/

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The list of options disappear, because you're telling the div to hide everything that goes beyond the div itself using `overflow:hidden`. Clearly, the dropdown menu is outside of the div.

Remove `overflow:hidden` and [it will work](http://jsfiddle.net/T9QHw/1/).

Comment: Thanks, I really had not noticed! (: