# Twitter Bootstrap Button Dropdown in jqGrid row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add bootstrap drop down button in a column of jqGrid row but when user clicks on the down arrow in the button so see the options, the options gets hidden behind the next row of the grid.

Have tried setting the zIndex but did not work.

Please suggest.

---

Solved:

The issues was fixed by overriding the jqGrid css ".ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view .ui-jqgrid-bdiv" to have overflow: visible

Comment: I just used the button drop down as specified on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns
 in a columnformatter for jqGrid. Nothing special from my end.

Comment: I know not to open old issues but the links are fallen and need to know what is the code that used to include the button. @araaku please could you post your code?. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question look similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067115/1416911

There's several solution (thanks to the bounty) to deal with the dropdown overflow issue.

Look at @ScottS answer in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by doing the following :

1. Add a class reference to the column model

{ name: 'edit', search: false, width: 90, align: 'center', sortable: false, **classes: "bootstrap_dropdown"** },

2. Add the bootstrap_dropdown css

   ```
   <style>
   td.bootstrap_dropdown {
       overflow:visible !important;
       white-space: normal !important;
   }
   ```
3. Edit the **ui.jqgrid.css**, and change the "`.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv`" element

   .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv 
      {position: relative; 
       margin: 0; 
       padding:0; 
       **overflow: visible!important;** 
       text-align:left;
      }
4. Add the dropdown to the row

   ```
           gridComplete: function () {
           var rows = $("#grid").getDataIDs();
           for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

               // code here 

               var edit = " ";
               edit = edit + "<div class='btn-group'>";
               edit = edit + "  <button type='button'  onclick=\"viewmodal.showEditPage('#grid'," + rows[i] + ");\" class='btn btn-primary  btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o lg'></i> Edit</button>";
               edit = edit + "  <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary  btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>";
               edit = edit + "    <span class='caret'></span>";
               edit = edit + "    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle Dropdown</span>";
               edit = edit + "  </button>";
               edit = edit + "  <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>";
               edit = edit + "    <li><a href='#' onclick=\"viewmodal.showUploadPage('#grid'," + rows[i] + "); return false;\"><i class='fa fa-upload lg'></i> Upload images</a></li>";
               edit = edit + "    <li class='divider'></li>";
               edit = edit + "    <li><a href='#' onclick=\"window.open('" + link + "','','');\"><i class='fa fa-search lg'></i> Preview web</a></li>";
               edit = edit + "    <li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-search lg'></i> Preview mobi</a></li>";
               edit = edit + "  </ul>";
               edit = edit + "</div>";

               // Add buttons to 'edit' column
               $("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData', rows[i], { edit: edit });

               // more code here
           };  
       }
   ```