# Show Twitter Bootstrap dropdown menu inside JQGrid

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I added twitter bootstrap dropdown menu to each JQGrid row using custom cell formatter. When I click the menu it is not fully visible. What style should I apply to show the dropdown menu on the very top of JQGrid row?

[image]

HTML:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="" title=" Actions   Update Delete" aria-describedby="jqg1_actions1">
   <div class="btn-group pull-right open">
      <div class="dropdown-backdrop"></div>
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-bell"></i> Actions  <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href=""><i class="icon-bell"></i> Update</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href=""><i class="icon-bell"></i> Delete</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: such problem could by typically solved by usage `z-index` CSS with large enough value for drop-down menu. If you would have problem to do this yourself you should post more full demo example which demonstrates the problem. You can prepare the demo using [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example.

Comment: @ohavryl did u manage to solve this problem ? me ran into this problem today... any advice ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found working solution for it. Just avoided using of dropdown control for now. But still interesting in using dropdown control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Accordion and button dropdown overflow issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959068/twitter-bootstrap-accordion-and-button-dropdown-overflow-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me by adding `style="position:absolute"` to first `div`

Comment: this will make an issue for the last row, the menu is above the cells, but still under the container of grid

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready");
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    $("#shop_filter").dd_select({
        prefix: "Shop by: ",
        formID: "main_form",
        hiddenFieldName:"filter",
        submitOnChange: false,
        ajaxCall:{}
    });
});
</script>
```

From the example http://www.vaskointeractive.com/demos/bootstrap-dd-select/

Answer (score 0):

z-index for the dropdown menu should be greater than the z-index for the jqGrid. So, go to the CSS files, and set z-index for the dropdown as 9999.