# my Bootstrap dropdown menu being covered by title bar of JQgrid

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.3.2.
Am trying to add bootstrap dropdown menu on my jqgrid but it is being covered by the title bar.
here is my code I have tried to dance around with z-index in css but the bar is always on top.

```
$('#jqGrid_toppager_right').append('<span class="dropdown"><button  class = "btn btn-primary  dropdown-toggle" type = "button" data-toggle = "dropdown">Download<span class = "caret"> </span></button ><ul class = "dropdown-menu exportdropmenu"   style=" z-index: 10000;" ><li onclick="exportraw(\'csv\')"> <a href = "#"  ><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> CSV </a></li></ul></span>');
```

[image]
Kindly help or refer any link with the same issue.

Comment: In order to help I need more information. The best way is to prepare a example. Also a lot of important information is missed - which CSS freamwork is used (jQuery UI or Bootstrap - if bootstrap which icon set), jQuery version, which browser and etc. Do you have made your custom modifications in the CSS? . I hope you understand that only with a demo we can help.

Comment: You may want to look at this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090949/show-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-inside-jqgrid/24805084#24805084)

Comment: I decided to use a select option... with some css. Thanks.